# How to determine $n(x)$ when the functional depends exclusively on $n(x)$ and $x$? (Fermat's principle)

Tags: optics, lagrangian-formalism, refraction, variational-principle, variational-calculus

Recently I was taught an introduction to calculus of variations in reference to a course on analytical mechanics, where one problem involved Fermat's principle, stating that the path taken by a light ray always minimizes the required travel time, mathematically formulated as:

$$t=\frac{1}{c}\int_{t_0}^{t_1} n(x,y)\sqrt{(\frac{dx(t)}{dt})^2+(\frac{dy(t)}{dt})^2}dt.$$

Customarily the function for the refractive index $n(x,y)$ is given and then one is asked to find $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ that minimize the travel time. On the other hand, I was wondering how to find the solution to the inverted problem, namely, assuming the optimized path is given by functions $x(t)$ $y(t)$, how to find a function $n(x,y)$ that results in this optimized path? Therefore, I simplified the problem by assuming that the refractive index and $y$ are functions of $x$: $n(x)$ and $y(x)$, reducing the problem to one variable. Then I reformulated the problem,

$$t=\frac{1}{c}\int_{x_0}^{x_1} n(x)\sqrt{1+(\frac{dy(x)}{dx})^2}dx,$$

where $y(x)$ is a function know in advance, $y=x^2$ for instance. Thus the functional would assume a form of $n(x)s(y(x))$ or $n(x)S(x)$ and applying the Euler-Lagrange equation to this functional eventually leads to the issue I couldn't resolve:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial n(x)}[n(x)S(x)]=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial}{\partial n(x)'}[n(x)S(x)]$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial n(x)}[n(x)S(x)]=0$$
$$S(x)=0$$
$$\sqrt{1+(\frac{dy(x)}{dx})^2}=0$$
$$1+(\frac{dy(x)}{dx})^2=0$$
Trying $y(x)=x^2$ for example, leads to
$$1+(2x)^2=0.$$

Where the last expression clearly defines no possible function for $n(x)$. In conclusion, irrespective of the chosen path $S(x)$, the function $n(x)$ I'm seeking is always eliminated by the partial derivative with respect to $n(x)$, which prevents finding the function $n(x)$. What flaw could be at play here, since I couldn't figure it out single-handedly.

Comment: You cannot optimise 
with respect to . The time is not minimal with respect to the refractive index; it's the path that is chosen such that the time is minimal. You should consider a variation of  with respect to  and extract the equation for  from there. Also, you will need to specify some boundary conditions because you will get a differential equation.

Comment: Careful, the path is stationary, not necessarily minimal.

Answer (score 1):

The Optical Path Length $\mathcal L$ of a light ray between points $\mathcal P_1$ and $\mathcal P_0$ is defined by
$$\mathcal L[\mathcal P_1, \mathcal P_0](n) = \int_{\mathcal P_0}^{\mathcal P_1}n(x_1,x_2,x_3)d\ell \tag{1}\label{1}$$ where $d\ell$ denotes the line element along the ray path. According to Fermat's principle this $\mathcal L$ is stationary in 1st order variation of $n$, that is $\delta \mathcal L=0$. To calculate what this means analytically we need to introduce a continuous parameter (not necessarily the "time" variable) along the ray path that identifies each point along the ray, say $u$ so that $x_k=x_k(u);k=1,2,3$ and $d\ell=\sqrt{\dot x_1(u)^2+\dot x_2(u)^2+\dot x_3(u)^2}du$ is the infinitesimal line element and the "dot" means differentiation with respect to $u$. Therefore the integral in $\eqref{1}$ can be written as
$$\mathcal L[\mathcal P_1, \mathcal P_0](n) = \int_{u_0}^{u_1}n(x_1,x_2,x_3)\sqrt{\sum_k \dot x_k(u)^2}du \tag{2}\label{2}$$
Taking variations:
$$\delta \mathcal L[u_1, u_0]= \delta\int_{u_0}^{u_1}n(x_1,x_2,x_3)\sqrt{\sum_k \dot x_k(u)^2}du \\
=\int_{u_0}^{u_1}\sum_k \left(\frac {\partial n}{\partial x_k}\delta x_k \left[\sum_k\dot x_k(u)^2\right]^{\frac{1}{2}}+n\frac{dx_k}{du}\frac{d}{du}(\delta x_k) \left[\sum_k\dot x_k(u)^2\right]^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right)du \\
=\int_{u_0}^{u_1}\sum_k (\delta x_k)\left(\frac {\partial n}{\partial x_k}\left[\sum_m\dot x_m(u)^2\right]^{\frac{1}{2}} - \frac{d}{du} \left[n\frac{dx_k}{du} \sum_m\dot x_m(u)^2\right]^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right)du \\
+ \left[\sum_k (\delta x_k)\left[n\frac{dx_k}{du} \sum_m\dot x_m(u)^2\right]^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right]_{\mathcal P_0}^{\mathcal P_1} \tag{3}\label{3}$$
Since the endpoints are fixed $\delta x_k(\mathcal P_0)=\delta x_k(\mathcal P_1) =0$ otherwise arbitrary infinitesimal and as the corresponding *Euler-Lagrange* equations we get
$$\nabla n = \frac{d}{d\ell}\left( n\frac{d\mathbf x}{d\ell}\right)=0 \tag {4}\label{4}$$ which is the standard (vector) expression for the propagation of the ray in an inhomogeneous isotropic medium.

Note that the introduction of the parameter $u$ is essential to the development and it cannot be replaced with the actual line length parameter $\ell$. While it is true that along a true ray $u=\ell$ but the variation imposed on the path changes it from being a *ray* to being something that is *not* a ray.

Comment: Thanks for the derivation, now could you determine $n(x,y,z)$ using the default vector equation for the propagation of light and given the path one would like the light to take? Since that's the ultimate goal, finding an expression for $n(x,y,z)$ given a path $r$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bl}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}} 
\newcommand{\e}{\bl=}
\newcommand{\p}{\bl+}
\newcommand{\m}{\bl-}
\newcommand{\gr}{\bl>}
\newcommand{\les}{\bl<}
\newcommand{\greq}{\bl\ge}
\newcommand{\leseq}{\bl\le}
\newcommand{\plr}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\blr}[1]{\left[#1\right]}
\newcommand{\lara}[1]{\langle#1\rangle}
\newcommand{\lav}[1]{\langle#1|}
\newcommand{\vra}[1]{|#1\rangle}
\newcommand{\lavra}[2]{\langle#1|#2\rangle}
\newcommand{\lavvra}[3]{\langle#1|\,#2\,|#3\rangle}
\newcommand{\vp}{\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}}
\newcommand{\hp}[1]{\hphantom{#1}} 
\newcommand{\x}{\bl\times}
\newcommand{\qqlraqq}{\qquad\bl{-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!\longrightarrow}\qquad}
\newcommand{\qqLraqq}{\qquad\boldsymbol{\e\!\e\!\e\!\e\!\Longrightarrow}\qquad}
\newcommand{\tl}[1]{\tag{#1}\label{#1}}
\newcommand{\hebl}{\bl{=\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!=}}$

Consider that the refraction path is represented by the curve $\,y\plr x\,$ so that light is propagating in a medium isotropic of variable refraction index $\,n\plr y\,$ supposing that the function $\,y\plr x\,$ is invertible.

At any point of the curve and in an infinitesimal level the Snell's Law is valid locally. This means that along the path we have the following running constant
\begin{equation}
n\plr y\sin\theta\plr y\e \texttt{const.}
\tl{01}
\end{equation}
where $\,\theta\plr y\,$ the angle between the tangent to the curve and the $\,y\m$axis. But then
\begin{equation}
\cot\theta\plr y\e\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{\dfrac{a}{b}}}
\tl{02}
\end{equation}
so
\begin{equation}
\sin\theta\plr y\e\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1\p\cot^2\theta\plr y\vphantom{\plr{\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}}^2}}}\e\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1\p\plr{\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}}^2}}
\tl{03}
\end{equation}
From equations \eqref{01},\eqref{03} we have the solution
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\:\:\:\:n\plr y\e \texttt{const.}\sqrt{1\p\plr{\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}}^2}\:\:\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{\dfrac{a}{b}}}}
\tl{04}
\end{equation}

$\hebl$

**Example 1 : Parabolic Curve**

In case of the parabolic curve
\begin{equation}
y\e x^2 
\tl{Ex-01}
\end{equation}
equation \eqref{04} yields
\begin{equation}
n\plr y\e n_0\sqrt{\,1\p 4y\:\vphantom{\tfrac{a}{b}}}
\tl{Ex-02}
\end{equation}
where $\,n_0\,$ the refraction index at the level $\,y\e0$.

$\hebl$

**Example 2 : Cycloid Curve**

In case of the cycloid curve
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
x&\e \lambda\m\sin\lambda\\
y&\e  1\m\cos\lambda\\
\end{split}
\tl{Ex-03}
\end{equation}
we have
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\e\dfrac{\sin\lambda}{1\m\cos\lambda}\e\cot\plr{\dfrac{\lambda}{2}}
\tl{Ex-04}
\end{equation}
so
\begin{equation}
1\p\plr{\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}}^2\e 1\p\cot^2\plr{\dfrac{\lambda}{2}}\e\dfrac{1}{\sin^2\plr{\dfrac{\lambda}{2}}}\e\dfrac{2}{1\m\cos\lambda}\e\dfrac{2}{y}
\tl{Ex-05}
\end{equation}
From equations \eqref{04}, \eqref{Ex-05} we have
\begin{equation}
n\plr y\e \dfrac{\texttt{const.}}{\sqrt{\,y\,\vphantom{\tfrac{a}{b}}}}
\tl{Ex-06}
\end{equation}
This result could be interpreted in relation to the motion of a particle on a brachistochrone curve under gravity with speed $\,v\e\sqrt{\,2gy\,\vphantom{a^2}}$.

$\hebl$